# Listview with multiple columns and const width/height cards in it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an problem to make scrollable listview with 2 columns (perfect would be flex columns count depends on screen width), with vertical scroll. Inside this list will be cards with const height and width.

I have tried gridview.count to make 2 columns but all the time its scaling to screen size (i have used childAspectRatio but dont work as expect). Also tried to use ConstrainedBox as  main widget to my card but doesnt work.

Want to mention, app is for iOS and android aswell.

```
class SongbookCardList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    /*24 is for notification bar on Android*/

    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;

    return Container(
      child: GridView.count(
        // childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 15, right: 15),
        mainAxisSpacing: 15,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          SongbookCard(),
          SongbookCard(),
          SongbookCard(),
          SongbookCard(),
          SongbookCard(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SongbookCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final SongBookWidgetStyle style = const SongBookWidgetStyle();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 150, maxHeight: 140, minHeight: 140, minWidth: 150),
      child: NeumorphicButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(
            BorderRadius.circular(style.borderRadius)),
        style: style.neumorphicStyle,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 8,
              child: ClipRRect(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                      color: ColorsExtension.appPurple),
                  width: 120,
                  height: 120,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                'test',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

View now:

[image: big device]
[image: small device]

View, I need:

[image: what need]

Answer (score 1):

please change this code (purple Container)

```
width: 120,
height: 120,
```

to

```
width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
height : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
```

---

**OR** you can add padding to your container and remove the sizes